# How to remove array elements from another array in mysql using JSON functions?

Tags: mysql, arrays

```
set @a = '["1","2","3"]';
set @b = '["4","2","3"]';
```

I have two json arrays.
Now I want to remove all the elements from @b from @a if it exists. else ignore.

Expected result:

```
["1"]
```

We can loop through @b and remove one by one from @a.

But I am looking for a best solution.

Is there somthing like JSON_REMOVE_ALL();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses JSON functions to extract elements in `@a` that are not in `@b`.

- [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) is used to convert `@a` into a table before
- [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) is used to check whether the element in `@a` exists in `@b`.
- Finally [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) aggregates the results into a single json array value

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

---

**Query #1**

```
set @a = cast('["1","2","3"]' as json);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
set @b = cast('["4","2","3"]' as json);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(num) result 
FROM
    JSON_TABLE(@a,"$[*]" COLUMNS(num json PATH "$" )) ta
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(@b,num,'$')=0;
```

| result |
| --- |
| ["1"] |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kUaEG1tWxpro5u958F9DdR/1)